# Starting solution automatically in VS 2017 via a batch file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 with 21 coded ui test cases inside it. I can open this solution via a batch file that was created. Batch file basically changes the directory to where the solution is and starts it (start Forms.sln). Is there any way I can run all the coded ui tests inside the solution automatically from the same batch file?

Any help would be appreciated

Russ

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use VSTEST.CONSOLE.exe. Check out this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx

Comment: Yes, I can change the destination to where vstest.console.exe is. Then I run vstest.console.exe (where my .sln file is located)\.....sln. It says starting test execution, please wait then nothing happens.

Comment: You need to have your app ready to receive the simulated operator input. For example if yours is a web app, you need to have the page displayed, logged in, etc. I did all of that with a bat file (using a PS script to start the web app and log on). And DO NOT do anything else on the machine while the tests are running.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't vstest is good for me then as my test cases have the log in etc as steps and this happens for every one. Thanks for the clarification though